# Post HTML code in a div box without getting it affected

Tags: html

Right now I have posted the code into a textbox because I want the code in plain text. Now I wonder if I can put the code into a div box instead i get the same result.

Right now:

```
<textarea id="copytext" readonly="readonly"><p>Show the p tags in plain text</p></textarea>
```

Comment: What's your question? It's really vague

Comment: Question updated, Please vote it up if it's better. @Chrillewoodz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code between `<pre>` tags so that it is not interpreted by your browser. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

```
<pre>&lt;img src="pic.jpg"&gt;</pre>
```

if you want a block of code this should be your markup:

```
<blockquote>
  <pre>
    <code>
        My pre-formatted "quoted" code here.
    </code>
  </pre>
</blockquote>
```

Also take a look at this tool: https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: Updated the code. This will get you the desired result. You have to escape the reserved HTML characters

Answer (score 0):

Testing 123, This shows the picture for me ????

```html
<blockquote>
  <pre>
    <code>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"/>
    </code>
  </pre>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: have a look at the second answer down [HERE, SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221067/display-html-markup-in-browser-without-it-being-rendered) , couldn't get it to work in the snippet tool as couldn't get the js to run on it before loading the image.