# how can i output to screen html as string?

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning Java Script. I want to use `document.write()` and to output html code as a string without actually running the code (just showing it on screen).

Is there any functiong that could help me do it?

Note: I'm trying to do it using Java Script (not jQuery)

Comment: Please see ErikE's answer on the matter in the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221067/display-html-markup-in-browser-without-it-being-rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document.write()`; it's the 20th-century way to build the DOM dynamically. Instead, put the string in the `textContent` of an element that you created in the initial HTML.

```js
var string = "<p>hi</p>";
document.getElementById("output").textContent = string;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Another way would be to create a text node and append it to the DOM.

```js
var string = "<p>Hi</p>";
var node = document.createTextNode(string);
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you replace < > with &lt; and &gt;.

```js
var string = '<html><p>hi</p></html>';
string = string.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
string = string.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
document.write(string);
```

http://codepen.io/calvinclaus/pen/eZwGmX?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

To add upon @Calvin Claus 's answer, you should also exchange '&' for `'&amp;'` and wrap your entire string in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to eliminate whitespace.
Note though that in general you shouldn't use `document.write()`, and instead change the textContent property of an element in the DOM (a div would probably be the case here), and you won't need to escape your HTML markup.